# how to color second p tag in html without using any style and class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 3 `p` tags,

```
<p> hi </p>
<p>hello</P>
<p>bye</P>
```

I want to color the 2nd `p` tag into red by only using pure css(not using any javascript).
without using any inline style and class how can i achieve this?

```
<p> hi </p>
<p>hello</P>
<p>bye</P>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>hi</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>bye</p>
```

However, as suggested by Hao Wu, it's better to use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) if you're looking for a certain tag (not a certain child):

```css
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>hi</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>bye</p>
```

Comment: it's better to use `:nth-of-type` since he's asking about the second `p` tag

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jack BashFords answer , if you want to style only even/odd numbered children you can use

```
.p:nth-child(even/odd) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

If you want more control you can use this formula **an+b**

You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

> “a” is an integer value
>
> “n” is the literal letter “n”
>
> “+” is an operator and may be either “+” or “-”
>
> “b” is an integer and is required if an operator is included in the
>   formula

For example 4n , targets only multiples of 4.

```
.p:nth-child(4n) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

This is the correct code.